# Vertical center text in CSS within a div

Tags: jquery, html, css, center, vertical-alignment

I've found some threads here on the issue but all were pre-CSS3.

Is there currently a way to center text vertically within a div? I'm making a simple webpage with 4 divs (code at the bottom of post).

Essentially the plan is to turn the plain divs into large buttons using jquery and have the page behave differently when they are clicked. But visually it looks poor right now because the text isn't centering vertically. With CSS3 and HTML is there currently a reliable way to resolve this?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jscript.js"></script>
<title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="containerDiv">
<div id="topLeft">Some text</div>
<div id="topRight">some more text</div><br />
<div id="bottomLeft">south west text</div>
<div id="bottomRight">south east text</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS follows

```
#containerDiv {
    background-color:#EEEEEE; 
    width:80%; 
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto;
    }

#topLeft {
    float:left; 
    width:50%; 
    background-color:#8800AA; 
    color:#EFEFEF; 
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto; 
    border-radius:10px; 
    text-align:center; 
    height:100px; 
    vertical-align:middle;
    }

#topRight {
    float:right; 
    width:50%; 
    background-color:#aa0088; 
    color:#EFEFEF; 
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto; 
    border-radius:10px; 
    text-align:center;
    height:100px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    }

#bottomLeft {
    float:left; 
    width:50%; 
    background-color:#00aa88; 
    color:#EFEFEF; 
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto; 
    border-radius:10px; 
    text-align:center;
    height:100px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    }

#bottomRight {
    float:right; 
    width:50%; 
    background-color:#0088aa; 
    color:#EFEFEF; 
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto; 
    border-radius:10px; 
    text-align:center;
    height:100px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    }
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/shashankreddy09/JxraN/
this might help

Answer (score 1):

As a trick, you can use `line-height` to center text vertically if you know the height of the div. Just set it to the same height as the div and it will center vertically:

```
.some-div {
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is acctually not really great way to that, but... 
- You can set the line-height property of your div to its height. 
- Or you display your div as a table cell and can then use the vertical-align property by setting it to middle

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `vertical-align: middle;` than you should also use `display: table-cell` and `display: table`. Another way to do this is to set `line-height` to 100px - this only works if you have only 1 line of text though (since these should be buttons that kinda makes sense).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#containerDiv {
    background-color:#EEEEEE; 
    width:80%; 
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto;
    }

#topLeft {
    float:left; 
    width:50%; 
    background-color:#8800AA; 
    color:#EFEFEF; 
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto; 
    border-radius:10px; 
    text-align:center; 
    height:100px; 
    line-height:100px;
    }

#topRight {
    float:right; 
    width:50%; 
    background-color:#aa0088; 
    color:#EFEFEF; 
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto; 
    border-radius:10px; 
    text-align:center;
    height:100px;
    line-height:100px;
    }

#bottomLeft {
    float:left; 
    width:50%; 
    background-color:#00aa88; 
    color:#EFEFEF; 
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto; 
    border-radius:10px; 
    text-align:center;
    height:100px;
    line-height:100px;
    }

#bottomRight {
    float:right; 
    width:50%; 
    background-color:#0088aa; 
    color:#EFEFEF; 
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto; 
    border-radius:10px; 
    text-align:center;
    height:100px;
    line-height:100px;
    }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qLaeE/)